# Compilation mode error output parse not matching

Tags: regular-expressions, compilation, compilation-mode

I've  below code

```lisp
(add-to-list 'compilation-error-regexp-alist 'kbd)
(add-to-list 'compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist
             '(kbd "^kmonad: Parse error at \\([0-9]+\\):\\([0-9]+\\):" 2 3))
```

And I want to parse

```
kmonad: Parse error at 36:1:
   |
36 | jdfkj
   | ^
```

But it doesn't match correctly in compilation buffer, I can't go to the line and column of the error, instead it points to first column of first line, and matches first regexp block as line number.
But regexp is correct
[image: re-build proof]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LINE and COLUMN entries (2 and 3 in your code) refers to the subgroup of the regexp. Your regexp only contains two subgroups, so they should be 1 and 2.

In addition, the first entry after the regexp is the filename (or nil), so it should be (REGEXP nil 1 2).

Comment: I tried `(kbd "^kmonad: Parse error at \\([0-9]+\\):\\([0-9]+\\):" 1 2)` but it doesn't work either. From their faces, I can say that 36 parsed as file name and 1 parsed as line number. https://paste.pics/4738cc4c3a70b7eb21e6189e146951ee

Comment: Ah, the first number is the file name (I missed that). Since you don't have a file name to match, try (REGEXP nil 1 2).

Comment: Thank you so much, it drove me insane!

Comment: Glad I could help!